# Uses native code in cordova application

Tags: android, cordova

I have a following code in native android

```
List<PackageInfo> PackList = getPackageManager().getInstalledPackages(0);
for (int i=0; i < PackList.size(); i++)
{
    PackageInfo PackInfo = PackList.get(i);
    if ( ( (PackInfo.applicationInfo.flags & ApplicationInfo.FLAG_SYSTEM) != 0) != true)
    {
        String AppName = PackInfo.applicationInfo.loadLabel(getPackageManager()).toString();
        Log.e("App" + Integer.toString(i), AppName);
    }
}
```

for getting information about installed application in mobile. I want to use in `cordova/phonegap` application.

1. How I use that?
2. What steps do I need?
3. Or is there anyway that same code use in different platforms
   (android,windows)?

I also checked this [link](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.2.0/guide_plugin-development_index.md.html) but didn't understand

Thanks In Advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To use native code in a phonegap app you have to create a phonegap plugin. This is actually pretty simple:

1) Create you phonegap plugin class, in this case the plugin only responds to the action "toast" to create a native Android toast:

```
public class ExamplePlugin extends CordovaPlugin {

    @Override
    public boolean execute(String action, JSONArray args, CallbackContext callbackContext) throws JSONException {
        if("toast".equals(action)) {
            // The first String in the arguments array is the text for the toast
            String text = args.getString(0);
            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this.cordova.getActivity(), text, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            toast.show();

            // With PluginResult you can send results back to the js layer.
            PluginResult result = new PluginResult(PluginResult.Status.OK, "--toast displayed.");
            result.setKeepCallback(true);
            callbackContext.sendPluginResult(result);
        }

        // Return true if everything worked as it should. If an error occurs return false.
        // Depending on this return value either the success or error callback is invoked.
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void initialize(CordovaInterface cordova, CordovaWebView webView) {
        super.initialize(cordova, webView);
        // Here you can perform some initialisations for your plugin.
    }
}
```

Then in the config.xml of your phonegap app you add this line:

```
<plugin name="ExamplePlugin" value="com.phonegap.example.ExamplePlugin" />
```

Name being the name by which you can call the plugin from javascript and value being the complete class name of your plugin.

Now you can call the plugin from javascript:

```
cordova.exec(successCallback, errorCallback, "ExamplePlugin", "toast", ["Hello Cordova!!1"]);
```

You supply two callbacks, the name of the plugin you want to call, the action you want to execute and an array of arguments, in our case the plugin is named "ExamplePlugin" the action is "toast" and we only have on string argument as text for our toast.

Of course this just works for Android. If you want the same functionality for different platforms e.g. iOS, Windows Phone etc. You are gonna have to create a plugin for each of them too.

Comment: is this simple java class (the first part of code)?

Comment: nothing. its ok i am checking. After testing i will post results. Thanks for you response

Comment: Well look at your logcat, probably it has something todo with timing, you can only call plugins after device ready or there are some problems finding/loading the plugin.

Comment: i put alert in both `successCallback` and `errorCallback`. First it shows be JS alert which i place in `errorCallback` after that it show `Hello Cordova !!` (output of this line `toast.show();`) now i don't understand what problem is there?

Comment: Oh I think I know where the problem is, give me a second to edit my answer.

Comment: I fixed it, the problem was just the return value of the execute method. I also added PluginResults to the example to demonstrate how to return values to the js layer.

Answer (score 0):

1. You will need to create a `PhoneGap/Cordova` `plugin`.
2. In the return data (the result) in the plugin you need to return the String.

For recent an example, check out this [blog post](http://teusink.blogspot.nl/2013/09/phonegap-android-androidpreferences.html). It works with `AndroidPreferences` feature and it uses both sending data and retrieving data.